# Jboss 5 - log file per application?

Tags: java, logging, jboss5.x

I want to have a custom configuration for my logs in my web application which uses jBoss 5 as application server.

I've done the following steaps.

1. Added **log4j.xml** with a custom config. into my *EAR/war/WEB-INF/classes* folder

Custom code (most important section from my log4j.xml file):

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/serverss.log"/>
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <!-- In AS 5.0.x the server log threshold was set by a system
       property. In 5.1 and later we are instead using the system
       property to set the priority on the root logger (see <root/> below)
  <param name="Threshold" value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
  -->
```

2.Created a **jboss-classloading.xml** file with this content:

```
 <classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" domain="simple-scoped" 

 parent-first="false" />
```

to enable classloader isolation and added it to *EAR/WAR/WEB-INF*

Well...it's not working and I am wondering why...?

I've also tried with a **jboss-app.xml** file with configuration:

```
<jboss-app>  
<loader-repository>   
com.example:archive=mahrds  
<loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>   
</loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

but I still do not see any file serverss.log in my default/log folder ...

Do you see anything wrong?

Thanks..